# Selecting nested columns from pyspark dataframe using spark-xml

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to select nested ArrayType from Pyspark Dataframe.

I want to select only items columns out of this dataframe. I dont know what wrong I am doing here.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shiporder orderid="str1234">
  <orderperson>ABC</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>XYZ</name>
    <address>305, Ram CHowk</address>
    <city>Pune</city>
    <country>IN</country>
  </shipto>
  <items>
  <item>
    <title>Clothing</title>
    <notes>
        <note>Brand:CK</note>
        <note>Size:L</note>
    </notes>
    <quantity>6</quantity>
    <price>208</price>
  </item>
  </items>
</shiporder>
```

Schema of dataframe.

```
root
 |-- _orderid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- items: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- item: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- notes: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- note: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- quantity: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- orderperson: string (nullable = true)
 |-- shipto: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)




df.show(truncate=False)
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
|_orderid|items                                                                                        |orderperson  |shipto                         |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
|str1234 |[[[[[color:Brown, Size:12]], 82.0, 1, Footwear], [[[Brand:CK, Size:L]], 208.0, 6, Clothing]]]|Vikrant Chand|[305, Giotto, Irvine, US, Amit]|
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
```

When I am selecting items column it is returning me null.

```
df.select([ 'items']).show()
+-----+
|items|
+-----+
| null|
+-----+
```

While select the same column with shipto(other nested column) solves the problem.

```
df.select([ 'items','shipto']).show()
+--------------------+--------------------+
|               items|              shipto|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[[[[[color:Brown,...|[305, Giotto, Irv...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: just use `df.select('items').show()` without square bracket.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I have tried. No luck

Comment: i tried both ways and it works for me so I can't say whats wrong

Comment: I have updated the question with XML dataset, can you please try with the same. I am not able to see column value using pyspark or scala-spark

Comment: Fixed it by upgrading the spark-xml version to 0.4.1

Comment: great to hear that

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in spark-xml which got fixed in 0.4.1

- [Issue-193](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/issues/196)